# How come you can use a Websockets-based service such as Pusher on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, pusher

Heroku does not provide (yet) Websockets and rely on long-polling instead ([see here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-socket-io-with-node-js-on-heroku)).

So I was surprized to see there is [an addon for Pusher](https://addons.heroku.com/pusher) which is a Websockets real-time messaging service (for real time apps)

How is it possible? Is Pusher on Heroku stack really using Websockets or do they actually provide only long-polling on Heroku?

I might be missing something here...

Answer (score 2):

Pusher is a 3rd party app. They have their own infrastructure and can do websockets. They are just a service that heroku customers can use. They are not running "on" heroku.

Answer (score 1):

Mitch is telling you correctly. I'm currently in the process of building an app on the Heroku network that utilizes Pusher. It's not hosted on your Heroku services. The websockets that are opened are between Pusher's servers and your clients. You send Pusher the information you want disseminated to the clients listening on whatever channel you specify. Your Heroku server and Pusher don't need an open connection to each other. Since you're telling Pusher what information you want to send, to the connections it has opened on it's servers. It may not be the cheapest option in the log run. But for fast prototyping, or just not wanting to deal with your own instant data transfer solution, Pusher does work well.

Comment: You publish messages to connected clients via Pusher using their (our) Web API. See http://pusher.com/docs

Comment: @leggeter Yes, that's what I was saying. You send pusher the information you want pushed (via their API) and your clients receive it in real time through the sockets they have opened between their (Pusher's) servers and your clients machine.

Comment: it's just you didn't say API or via an HTTP call. I just wanted to confirm that the connection to Pusher isn't via some kind of persistent connection. Just a clarification. I did upvote :)